# using {{ twig variables }} inside external jquery

Tags: theming, 8, javascript

Developing a D8 theme, I am loading an external .js file containing some jQuery code (so it is not inside the TWIG template).

Is it possible to access and modify TWIG variables like `{{ myvariable }}` inside the external jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to access Twig variables in jQuery directly. Instead access the content of PHP variables inside of an external jQuery code by attaching them to drupalSettings. See the documentation:

> Attaching configurable JavaScript
>
> In some cases, you may want to add JavaScript to a page that depends
>   on some computed PHP information.
>
> In this case, create a JavaScript file, define and attach a library
>   just like before, but also attach JavaScript settings and have that
>   JavaScript file read those settings, via drupalSettings (the successor
>   to Drupal 7's Drupal.settings). However, to make drupalSettings
>   available to our JavaScript file, we have to do the same work as we
>   had to do to make jQuery available: we have to declare a dependency on
>   it.
>
> ```
> cuddly-slider:
>   version: 1.x
>   js:
>     js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
>   dependencies:
>     - core/jquery
>     - core/drupalSettings
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/cuddly-slider';
> $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['fluffiness']['cuddlySlider']['foo'] = 'bar';
> ```
>
> Where 'bar' is some calculated value.
>
> Then cuddly-slider.js will be able to access
>
> `drupalSettings.fluffiness.cuddlySlider.foo (and it will === 'bar').`

https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets