# How do I get a module path?

Tags: 8, javascript

I'm creating a module in Drupal 8 and I need to define a relative path to mymodule to pass it on a JavaScript file like this.

```
$scope.getPlatformIcon = function (_platform) {
     var modulePath = "/modules/mymodule"
     switch (_platform) {
         case "youtube":
         case "twitter":
         case "instagram":
         case "facebook":
             return modulePath+"/img/"+_platform+".png";
     }
     return false;
};
```

In Drupal 7 I could use the following.

```
var modulePath = Drupal.settings.mymodule.basePath;
```

For the Drupal 8 root directory, I could use the following.

```
drupalSettings.path.baseUrl
```

I didn't find how to get the module path.

How can I do it with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Drupal 8 this drupal setting is not available by default. You can check the existing variables by looking for this JSON array on the HTML page:

```
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{
```

To add the module path variable use this code:

```
$build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mymodule']['mylib']['path'] = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath('mymodule');
```

For more info about drupalSettings see:

[using {{ twig variables }} inside external jquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200041/using-twig-variables-inside-external-jquery)

---

**Update Drupal 9.3**

Use the new service:

```
\Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath('mymodule')
```

See the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2940438

This function drupal_get_path() and the even more used [file_create_url()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2940031) will be the major deprecations for Drupal 10. Since Drupal versions prior to 9.3 are no longer supported it's now time to update the code in preparation for Drupal 10. Always check the change records for the correct replacement code.

Answer (score 31):

To answer the original question (*how do I get a module path*), and not taking into account the javascript attachment part here is OO friendly solution (without showing the dependency injection itself):

```
$module_handler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
$module_path = $module_handler->getModule('my_module')->getPath();
```

This will give you back the following (of course also depends on how your directory structure looks like)

```
"modules/custom/my_module"
```

`drupal_get_path` is indeed faster to write. However, it calls the same service above statically which makes your code unable to unit test (also not to mention the dependencies of your class are not visible).
Long story short: if you choose to make things Quick&Dirty go for `drupal_get_path` any other cases use the right service yourself with a proper dependency injection.

Comment: To get the absolute file system path: `\Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(\Drupal::service('module_handler')->getModule('my_module')->getPath())`

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Drupal 9.3 you can also get it by:

```
$themePath =
  \Drupal::service('extension.path.resolver')
  ->getPath('module', 'my_module');
```